# The Hair dynamics makes the hair 'seperate' or 'float' away from model, it is my first time using particle

Tags: modeling, particles, hair

[image]

I am very new to blender, I hope I'm not a burden, I am following this tutorial. but I am trying to go for a different style, I guess maybe a messed up? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgmJ7rLGvCg&list=PLunylD9CvgoSTCVAOD5hHEFlXSGhvVDVZ&index=4

Comment: sorry if the theme is too bright

Comment: Could be the collision. Have you applied the scale to your model? (press Ctrl+A and select *Scale* in *Object* mode)

Comment: Thank you, It worked, normally I don't think people use particle for hair but It caught my eye and I'm already used to particle. Thanks